# Как распечатать чистое лямбда-выражение в Haskell (в ghci)?

Tags: haskell

Например я пишу `(\x y -> x) (\x -> x) 12` и чтоб распечатал буквально `(\x->x)`
(и не тип T->T (пробовал через :t))
Чтоб не писал "No instance for (Show..." и чтоб распечатывал любую анонимную функцию, независимо от сигнатуры. То есть, чтобы можно было использовать Haskell как интерпретатор чистого лямбда-исчисления (но с синтаксисом Haskell)

Comment: нашел в сети интерпретатор чистого \-исчисления, но он крайне неудобен, всюду требует явно указывать скобки для группировки (даже где они подразумеваются по умолчанию), получается какой-то кошмар из скобок. Вот, попробуйте сами: https://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~gongliang13/lambda/#firstPage

Answer (score 1):

Боюсь, что никак: в Haskell не предусмотрено средств для этого, как и в других  компилируемых языках - тот же интерпретатор GHCi построен поверх компилятора и перед выполнением выражений выполняет их компиляцию - попробуйте набрать `ghc --interactive` ;-)
Это во-первых, во-вторых пример кода, приведённый Вами, не верен.

Comment: Нет ли каких-либо непрямых в каком-либо смысле "хитрых" способов? Непонятно где ошибка в приведенном примере кода?

Comment: Увы, нет - по-крайней мере в GHC - в результате компиляции (exe-файле или в машинных кодах в памяти) не хранится исходный код. Теоретически, можно решить подобную задачу с помощью расширения Template Haskell - оно поддерживается GHC - это средство позволяет автоматизировать генерацию кода и на этом уровне есть доступ к дереву синтаксического разбора кода, но я не знаю писал ли кто-то такую библиотеку :( Ошибка: приведённый код не работает в ghci: `parse error on input ``.'`. Более правильный (с точки зрения Haskell) код `(\x y -> x) (\x -> x) 12` - он ведёт себя ровно так, как Вы описали.

Comment: Спасибо, исправил

Comment: Может быть можно не через шаблоны, а как-нибудь через типы?

Comment: Чтобы получить выражение, вычисляющее функцию, нужно иметь доступ к формальной структуре, описывающей процесс вычисления: исходным кодам, дереву синтаксического разбора. Библиотеки Template Haskell, насколько я знаю, имеют доступ к дереву синтаксического разбора обычного Haskell-кода. Т.е. возможна библиотека, содержащая функцию `extractFunctionExpession :: t -> String` такую, что выражение `extractFunctionExpression (\x -> x)` вернёт строку похожую на `"\x -> x"`